# How to catch an execption when dot sourcing a ps1

Tags: powershell, import, try-catch

```
Try
{
    . \\isrv\functions\Functions.ps1
}
Catch
{
    #Write-Logging -level Error "IMPORT : Failed doing an import of   functions.ps1
}

\\isrv does not exist , but still its not going into the catch.
```

When i try `. \\isrv\functions\Functions.ps1` outside the try/catch i get the     error : path or file not know so i could use that to build up my catch.. yet inside the try catch its not working??

Comment: The `Catch` branch action  is commented up by leading `#` (number sign or hash symbol) therefore it _seems_ to do nothing :)

Comment: Inside the `catch` block, `$_` will reference the exception: `try{ . \\non\existing\file.ps1 }catch{ Write-Host "PANIC PANIC PANIC, IT FAILED:" -ForegroundColor Red; Write-Host $_ }`